# How to prevent Continuous ACK packets to my server

Tags: networking, packet, linux-server

I found my server got continuous ACK packets from different sites, never stop, like below(I used tcpdump to capture)

1. the remote sites use https.
2. contains akamai, amazon..etc, which should be legit.

I'm wondering there are unsuccessful connections to these sites before, then this happened.

I would like to know how to not get these ACK packets.

```
23:12:37.555238 IP prg02s12-in-f1.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.52285: Flags [FP.], seq 0, ack 1, win 64240, length 0
23:12:37.555242 IP 17.167.192.152.https > 192.168.192.128.49292: Flags [FP.], seq 0, ack 1, win 64239, length 0
23:12:37.555246 IP prg02s12-in-f14.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.49961: Flags [FP.], seq 0:55, ack 1, win 64240, length 55
23:12:37.555253 IP 17.164.1.38.https > 192.168.192.128.49844: Flags [FP.], seq 0:37, ack 1, win 64240, length 37
23:12:37.555293 IP a2-16-84-128.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com.https > 192.168.192.128.49850: Flags [FP.], seq 0:31, ack 1, win 64240, length 31
23:12:37.555301 IP 125.209.252.12.https > 192.168.192.128.49929: Flags [FP.], seq 0, ack 1, win 64240, length 0
23:12:37.555307 IP prg02s12-in-f4.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.49964: Flags [FP.], seq 0:55, ack 1, win 64240, length 55
23:12:37.655195 IP fra07s31-in-f1.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.58291: Flags [FP.], seq 0, ack 1, win 64240, length 0
23:12:37.655227 IP ec2-54-193-107-210.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.https > 192.168.192.128.50448: Flags [FP.], seq 0:7, ack 1, win 64240, length 7
23:12:37.655233 IP fra07s31-in-f1.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.41618: Flags [FP.], seq 0:110, ack 1, win 64240, length 110
23:12:37.655238 IP ec2-54-154-38-161.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.5223 > 192.168.192.128.48941: Flags [FP.], seq 0:7, ack 1, win 64240, length 7
23:12:37.655243 IP fra07s31-in-f1.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.54130: Flags [FP.], seq 0:110, ack 1, win 64240, length 110
23:12:37.655247 IP prg02s12-in-f1.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.52285: Flags [FP.], seq 0, ack 1, win 64240, length 0
23:12:37.655254 IP 17.167.192.152.https > 192.168.192.128.49292: Flags [FP.], seq 0, ack 1, win 64239, length 0
23:12:37.655259 IP prg02s12-in-f14.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.49961: Flags [FP.], seq 0:55, ack 1, win 64240, length 55
23:12:37.655265 IP 17.164.1.38.https > 192.168.192.128.49844: Flags [FP.], seq 0:37, ack 1, win 64240, length 37
23:12:37.655271 IP a2-16-84-128.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com.https > 192.168.192.128.49850: Flags [FP.], seq 0:31, ack 1, win 64240, length 31
23:12:37.655275 IP 125.209.252.12.https > 192.168.192.128.49929: Flags [FP.], seq 0, ack 1, win 64240, length 0
23:12:37.655281 IP prg02s12-in-f4.1e100.net.https > 192.168.192.128.49964: Flags [FP.], seq 0:55, ack 1, win 64240, length 55
```

Comment: almost every packet in a TCP connection should have the ACK flag set to 1. Additionally for a number of half opened connections, I would expect lots of incomming connection requests with SYN set and no ACK. every other packet in the connection would have an ACK flag set.

Comment: You are right, I captured some packets with wireshark, these packets should be [SYN,ACK], not [ACK]. There are some unknown reasons that there are no ACK packets. Is it possible to drop these kind of packets automatically?

Comment: You're sending data to these web servers, and they're acknowledging it. What makes you think this is anything other than what it looks like -- legitimate data being acknowledged?

Comment: As @DavidSchwartz stated, that is normal behavior for TCP. The only way I know of to reduce ACKs is SACK, but both sides must agree to use it. With SACK, an ACK is sent after a group of packets instead of just one and will detail any pieces not received. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2018.txt